# Is there any way to repeat a row in a grid in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm a newcomer to QML. You can reproduce the following example by replacing `Note` and `FixedNote` with `Button`. I'm trying to get the last row to repeat a variable number of times. When the user clicks "Add chord", I want to add another repeat of the last row, and when the user clicks "Remove chord", I want to add remove the last row. My intuition (a nested repeater for the last row) doesn't seem to be working?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Justly")
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Column {
            spacing: 20
            Row {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                spacing: 5
                TextField {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    placeholderText: qsTr("100")
                    width: 50
                }
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    text: "bpm"
                }
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    text: "with key starting at"
                }
                TextField {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    placeholderText: qsTr("440")
                    width: 60
                }
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    text: "hz"
                }

            }
            Row {
                spacing: 20
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                Grid {
                    id: grid
                    columns: 3
                    spacing: 15
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    horizontalItemAlignment: Grid.AlignHCenter
                    verticalItemAlignment: Grid.AlignVCenter
                    Text {
                        text: "Chord"
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: "Key"
                    }
                    Repeater{
                        id: voice_names
                        model: 1
                        TextField {
                            placeholderText: model.index + 1
                            width: 70
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: "Play"
                    }
                    FixedNote { }
                    Repeater {
                        id: voice_notes
                        model: 1
                        Note { }
                    }
                }
                Column {
                    spacing: 5
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    Button {
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        text: "Add voice"
                        onClicked: {
                            grid.columns = grid.columns + 1
                            voice_names.model = voice_names.model + 1
                            voice_notes.model = voice_notes.model + 1
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        text: "Remove voice"
                        onClicked: {
                            voice_names.model = voice_names.model - 1
                            voice_notes.model = voice_notes.model - 1
                            grid.columns = grid.columns - 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Column {
                spacing: 5
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                Button {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: "Add chord"
                    onClicked: {
                        // chords.model = chords.model + 1
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: "Remove chord"
                    onClicked: {
                        // chords.model = chords.model - 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the console output when you run the app, you'll see that `chords` is an undefined id.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's why I commented it out. Wrapping the last row in `Repeater` didn't work. I'll leave a comment below with what I tried.

Comment: I think an explanation of what `chords` is supposed to refer to and maybe seeing the code related to that would help. Otherwise, I would expect the code you posted to never work and am not sure how to help you.

Comment: I think you have to source your chords from a `ListModel`, to which to you can append `ListElement`'s with a javascript call. That list can than be tied to a `model` property of, I think, a `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to create a matrix of `TextField` items. And your intuition is right, you can use two nested repeaters for that. One to generate rows and and other to generate columns.

Here is an example how you can do that. Have two properties that hold numbers of rows and columns and then use this properties as models for the Repeaters:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Item {
  anchors.fill: parent
  anchors.margins: 30

  property int numRows: 4
  property int numCols: 5

  Column {
    spacing: 10

    Text {
      height: 50
      text: "QML input matrix demo"
      font.bold: true
      font.pixelSize: 20
    }

    Row {
        spacing: 10

        Text {
          width: 70
          text: " " 
        }

        Repeater {
          model: numCols

          delegate: Text {
            width: 70
            text: "Col " + index 
          }
        }
      }

    Repeater {
      model: numRows

      delegate: Row {
        spacing: 10

        property int rIndex: index

        Text {
          width: 70
          anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
          text: "Row " + index 
        }

        Repeater {
          model: numCols

          delegate: TextField {

            property int cIndex: index

            width: 70
            text: rIndex + "," + cIndex 
          }
        }
      }
    }

    Item {
      height: 50
      width: 1
    }

    Row {
      spacing: 5

      Button {
        text: "Add col"
        onClicked: numCols = numCols + 1
      }

      Button {
        text: "Remove col"
        onClicked: numCols = numCols - 1
      }

      Button {
        text: "Add row"
        onClicked: numRows++
      }

      Button {
        text: "Remove row"
        onClicked: numRows--
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Here is also a working version of the snippet:
https://cutes.io/project/Kg

Comment: Thanks! This look great! I ended up doing a nested listview because repeater would delete all the data whenever a new row was added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the grid and making a list of nested listview. My code looked like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

Window {
    id: window
    width: window.square_side + window.note_width * 10 + window.spacing * 10
    height: 600
    property int spacing: 5
    property int note_height: 140
    property int note_width: 110
    property int square_side: 40
    property int long_width: 100
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Justly")
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        height: song.height
        Column {
            id: song
            spacing: window.spacing
            Row {
                spacing: window.spacing
                Button {
                    text: "▶"
                    onClicked: {
                        var result = []
                        for (var i = 0; i < chords.count; i++) {
                            result.push(chords.get(i))
                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
                    }
                }
                Row {
                    spacing: window.spacing
                    TextField {
                        placeholderText: qsTr("100")
                        width: window.long_width
                    }
                    Text {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        text: "bpm"
                    }
                }
                Row {
                    spacing: window.spacing
                    TextField {
                        placeholderText: qsTr("440")
                        width: window.long_width
                    }
                    Text {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        text: "hz"
                    }
                }
            }
            ListView {
                id: chords_list
                spacing: window.spacing
                width: 1000
                height: chords.count * (window.note_height + window.spacing)
                orientation: ListView.Vertical
                model: chords
                delegate: Row {
                    spacing: window.spacing
                    ListView {
                        id: notes_list
                        spacing: window.spacing
                        width: notes.count * (window.note_width + window.spacing)
                        height: window.note_height
                        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                        model: notes
                        delegate: Row {
                            spacing: window.spacing
                            Column {
                                spacing: window.spacing
                                Row {
                                    spacing: window.spacing
                                    Column {
                                        spacing: spacing
                                        TextField {
                                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                            placeholderText: numerator
                                            width: window.square_side
                                            onEditingFinished: {
                                                numerator = text * 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ToolSeparator {
                                            orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                                        }
                                        TextField {
                                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                            placeholderText: denominator
                                            width: window.square_side
                                            onEditingFinished: {
                                                denominator = text * 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Text {
                                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                        text: "* 2"
                                    }
                                    TextField {
                                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.Top
                                        placeholderText: octave
                                        width: window.square_side
                                        onEditingFinished: {
                                            octave = text * 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                Row {
                                    spacing: window.spacing
                                    Button {
                                        text: "▶"
                                        width: window.square_side
                                    }
                                    Text {
                                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                        text: "for"
                                    }
                                    TextField {
                                        placeholderText: beats
                                        width: window.square_side
                                        onEditingFinished: {
                                            beats = text * 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        text: "←"
                        width: window.square_side
                        visible: notes.count > 1
                        onClicked: {
                            notes.remove(notes.count - 1)
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        text: "→"
                        width: window.square_side
                        visible: notes.count < 10
                        onClicked: {
                            notes.append({numerator: 1, denominator: 1, octave: 0, beats: 1})
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "↑"
                visible: chords.count > 0
                onClicked: {
                    chords.remove(chords.count - 1)
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "↓"
                onClicked: {
                    chords.append({notes: [{numerator: 1, denominator: 1, octave: 0, beats: 1}]})
                }
            }
        }
        ListModel {
            id: chords
        }
    }
}
```